# What is the difference between if and if-then?

Tags: semantics, grammar, meaning, conditionals

According to [33]. Davis, W. (1983). Weak and strong conditionals. Pacific Philosophical Quarterly, 64(1), 57-71., there exist two versions of if conditional as shown below.

> (1) a. If it is humid, the TV will work.
> b. If it is humid, then the TV will work.    (Davis  1983)
>
> (2) a. If you develop something complicated, you need complicated people.
> b. If you develop something complicated, then you need complicated people.

In (1)a, the reading is that the humid condition does not effect the TV's work, while in (1)b, there exists the unknown connection between the humid condition and the TV's work. I don't know whether this effect also occurs in (2). Is this weak vs. strong effect pervasive or just limited to the case of (1)?

Comment: I don't agree with your (or your source's) interpretation of the alleged contrast between (1)a and b, and I don't think that's [what Davis is trying to say](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1468-0114.1983.tb00184.x).

Comment: This is really about a philosophical theory and conventions of contemporary logic, not about natural language. It would be better answered on Philosophy SE.

Comment: @6726 This has to do with the difference in meaning between natural language *if* and natural language *if then*, surely?

Comment: That's rather like asking whether _He said that S_ is different in meaning from _He said S_. In material implication, _then_ is optional.

Comment: One is a conditional sentence and the other is a logical proposition.

Answer (score 2):

There is no widely successful account, in  linguistics or in philosophy, which gives distinct truth conditions for conditionals with and without *then*—[Davis (1983)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1468-0114.1983.tb00184.x) notwithstanding.

In contrast, a widely held view that Davis was arguing against *has* been overturned since he was writing. He observed (p.57):

> It is generally assumed that “then” is a redundant part of conditionals, that “If A, C” and “If A, then C” are synonymous.

The paper which largely overturned this view, influential in both philosophy and linguistics, is  [Iatridou (1993) On the contribution of conditional *then*](http://lingphil.mit.edu/papers/iatridou/natural_language_semantics.pdf).

According to Iatridou, *If P, then Q* carries the presupposition that in at least some *Not P* cases, *Q* will also not be true. So we are most likely to use *then* when we would not expect *Q* to happen unless *P*.

Because not all instances of *If P, Q* carry this same presupposition, so the story goes, it is possible to find sentences in which *then* will be infelicitous:

> (1)  ?Even if my leg falls off, then I will make it to your wedding.

There are various reasons why one might disagree with the arguments set forth in Iatridou (1993), not least because many of the grammaticality judgements therein are highly debatable. However, it does seem intuitive that the use of *then* might have a slightly contrastive effect. The use of the *If P, Q* construction already sets up *P* as a background for a *Q* eventuality. In other words it is widely agreed that *If P, Q* already means something like *In the case of P, Q.* The use of *If P, **then** Q* is then a bit like saying *In the case of P, in **that** case Q*, where the effective contribution of the truth-conditionally redundant *then* is to pick out *P* backgrounds in contrast with other ones. Though, as stated, that's just intuition.

---

<sup>Interestingly, Iatridou states in her opening line (p.171):</sup>

> <sup>It is widely assumed that the appearance of *then* in a conditional is optional and that it contributes nothing to the meaning of the conditional as a whole <sup>1</sup></sup>

<sup>That superscript 1 at the end of the sentence directs to the following footnote:</sup>

> <sup>The only exception that I know of is found in the philosophical literature, Davis (1983).</sup>

<sup>So it seems as though Iatridou did not manage to find anyone converted to the Davis (1983) account either.</sup>

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would say that _then_ will be infelicitous in **every** _even if_ sentence. I can’t think of a single example where it isn’t.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I’d definitely agree. That’s why it was an easy example to come up with!